# open a WCF in express editions

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have created a WCF project in VS2008, pro edition. Trying to open the same on a test machine that has VS express editions and error i get is

'the project type is not supported by this installation'

Comment: that's definitely not a WCF problem - what other projects are in your solution? WCF is in .NET 3.0 and up - regardless of what Visual Studio edition you use.

Comment: the other projects that my WCF project uses are VS 2008 C#

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're opening your project in Visual Web Developer 2008 Express and not Visual C# 2008 Express.  Opening the project in the latter will produce this error message.